# can a windows 8 application listen for events / external web service calls - web hooks

Tags: wcf, events, notifications

I am looking to build a windows 8 RT application which needs to be activated by events that happen out side of the windows 8 application.

I have seen lots of potential ways this MGIHT be able to be accomplished, but nothing that seems to cover all "events" :-)

The scenario I am hopg to deal with is as follows

Windows 8 surface app sits in a "listening" mode. PC on the network carries out an action. The action could probably result in a web service call. The windows 8 app listens for the call and then opens a screen.

The std method seems to be to reccomend using Windows Notification Services, but this seems over kill and there might not be access from an internal network to an external WNS.

I have seen blogs on local notifications, where the app listens ( in this case the app will be listening in full screen mode ) and reacts.

I have also seen blogs on creating a local windows service on the application.

This seems to suggest that an windows service could expose an endpoint, which when hit with a call could raise some event to the app to make it respond e.g. open / close a form etc.

Is this a common pattern, or is there a better way to do this ?

I would be keen to hear what if anything others have used to solve this issue ?

I really want to avoid the app having to poll somewhere every second or two.

The other last resort is to use a fileMonitor type actvity and get the service to write a file or for the external PC to write a file into a shared dir ?

B...